# Is there an analytical solution to $\int_1^\infty \frac {dx}{\prod_{i=0}^n (x+i)}$

Tags: definite-integrals

In a problem from physics, I have to deal with this apparently simple function $$I_n=n! \int_1^\infty \frac {dx}{\prod_{i=0}^n (x+i)}$$ $(n\geq 1)$, the result of which being, for sure, something like $\log\left(\frac {p_n}{q_n}\right)$ where $p_n,q_n$ are whole numbers which become to be very large even for small values of $n$ (e.g : $p_5=67108864$, $q_5=61509375$).

For any particular $n$, the value of $I_n$ can be exactly computed (partial fraction decomposition) but I need accurate (or better, exact) results for large values of $n$.

In the past, someone proposed as a first approximation   $$I_n\approx\frac{0.694}{n^{1.285}}$$ which I have been able to reproduce almost exactly curve fitting the values for $1\leq n \leq 20$. But this is too inaccurate for my application. For example, the above formula would give $I_{100}\approx 0.001868$ for an exact value $\approx 0.002011$.

Would someone have an idea either for an exact solution (probably a reccurence relation ?) or a much better approximation ?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Thanks to heropup's exact solution and Winther's work around the asymtotics
$$I_n = \frac{1}{n\log(n)}\left[1 - \frac{\gamma}{\log(n)} + \frac{\gamma^2 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}}{\log^2(n)} + \frac{\psi ^{(2)}(1)-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}}{\log^3(n)} +  \cdots \right]  $$ incredible progress has been done.

I give below a few numbers for illustration
 $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{exact} & \text{approx} \\
 100 & 0.00201125049 & 0.00198077851 \\
 200 & 0.00088234568 & 0.00087283768 \\
 300 & 0.00054857248 & 0.00054365188 \\
 400 & 0.00039259469 & 0.00038949113 \\
 500 & 0.00030329103 & 0.00030111383 \\
 600 & 0.00024583983 & 0.00024420737 \\
 700 & 0.00020596177 & 0.00020468064 \\
 800 & 0.00017675824 & 0.00017571890 \\
 900 & 0.00015450281 & 0.00015363806 \\
 1000 & 0.00013701199 & 0.00013627810
\end{array}
\right)$$

Using the exact values for  $100 \leq n \leq 1500$ (step $\Delta n=50$) and performing a linear regression based on the suggested model $$I_n\approx \frac{1}{n\log(n)} \sum_0^3\frac {a_i}{\log^i(n)}$$ leads to
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a_0 & +0.99283 & 0.0005 & \{+0.992,+0.994\} \\
 a_1 & -0.48997 & 0.0076 & \{-0.506,-0.474\} \\
 a_2 & +1.82615 & 0.0418 & \{+1.740,+1.912\} \\
 a_3 & -4.52490 & 0.0755 & \{-4.681,-4.369\} \\
\end{array}$$ giving a maximum absolute error $<10^{-8}$. This is already an incredibly good fit.

Comment: Do I have this correct? For $n=0, I_{0}= \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x}=\ln\infty-\ln1$?

Comment: @Bacon. $n\geq 1$. Thanks for pointing. I shall edit.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense now,  Thanks.

Comment: @Winther. I agree with you, for sure. This is the point where I am stuck ! Any idea will be more than welcome. Cheers.

Comment: @Winther. Again, I agree with you. As you wrote, the problem is to simplify to .... something ! Thanks for helping.

Comment: The sum form of the integral (as given in heropup's answer below) is treated in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125279/147873). Unfortunately it only gives the first term in the asymptotic, $\frac{1}{n\log(n)}$, but the method used can with some work be extended to give more terms. Since the next term in the series is $\frac{1}{n(\log(n))^2}$ one probably needs several terms to get good accuracy for the cases you are interested in.

Comment: I had a go at trying to derive the asymptotic expansion. It was quite a mess. This is what I got so far $$I_n = \frac{1}{n\log(n)}\left[1 - \frac{\gamma}{\log(n)} + \frac{\gamma^2 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}}{\log^2(n)} + \frac{\psi ^{(2)}(1)-\gamma ^3-\frac{\gamma  \pi ^2}{2}}{\log^3(n)} +  \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\log^4(n)}\right)\right] + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2\log(n)}\right)$$ This is accurate to a few percent at $n=100$ and down to $\sim 1\%$ at $n=1000$ so still not good enough.

Comment: @Winther. Thank you very much. Be sure I really appreciate. What you did will be the start of further investigation on my side. I shall let you know. Thanks again. Cheers.

Comment: @MrYouMath. Thanks for pointing the typo. It is $n$. Shame on me. Cheers.

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64971) that's linked to in the answer by David Speyer that Winther linked to above? Your sum is the difference of two sums of the form discussed in that question:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom nk\log(1+k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k(-1)^k\log k-\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk(-1)^k\log k\;.
$$

That doesn't yield a useful approximation because the expansion there only goes up to $O\left(\log^{-3}(n)\right)$, but perhaps you can find something useful in the answers and references given there.

Comment: Two more related questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114155, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066144.

Comment: @joriki. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is relatively straightforward to show that for positive integers $n$, $$f_n(x) = B(x,n+1) = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(x+n+1)} = \frac{1}{x\binom{x+n}{n}} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}}{x+k}.$$  Consequently, $$\int_{x=1}^\infty f_n(x) \, dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \left(\log (x+k) - \log(1+k)\right).$$  The limit for the upper endpoint terms of course is zero; this leaves us with $$\int_{x=1}^\infty f_n(x) \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k} \log (1+k).$$  From here we could start to do things with even and odd cases of $n$.  I haven't the time to look at large $n$ asymptotics but it should not be difficult.

Comment: This is, for sure, totally correct. The problem is computing time. Thanks for answering. If you have an idea about asymptotics, this would be great for getting a new and better approximation. Cheers.