# How to compute $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x(x+1)\dots(x+k)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can somebody give me hint for computing following integral
$$\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x(x+1)\dots(x+k)}$$
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
My idea was to write that as
$$\frac{A_1}{x}+\dots + \frac{A_k}{x+k}$$
and integrate that but from that I haven't got anything.

Comment: Writing out a few $A_k$ it appears that there is a pattern

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114155/computing-int-0-infty-frac1x1x2-cdotsxn-mathrm-dx

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066144/improper-integral-int-1-infty-frac-mathrm-dxxx1x2-cdotsxn

Answer (score 2):

I think if you can find a way to generalise the partial fraction decomposition that would give you the easiest form but I cannot think of a way to do it.

I do know that:
$$\prod_{i=0}^k(x+i)=x(x+1)_k$$
where $(x+1)_k$ represents the rising factorial i.e.
$$(x+1)_k=\frac{(x+k)!}{x!}$$ so you could represent your integral as:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x+k+1)}\,dx$$
however I was not able to progress any further than this